# Queries regarding 'backport-android-bluetooth'

Tags: android, bluetooth, backport

I have started working on android just 1 month back (so please consider my question even if it looks simple). I have my Bluetooth code running on Android 2.2. So I am working on using backport-android-bluetooth to migrate it to Android 1.6 (as I have some old pads with 1.6).

I came across foll. link: http://code.google.com/p/backport-android-bluetooth/

I have queries regarding point no. 1 and 2 under 'Install' which are as follows: 
1. download backport-android-bluetooth2.jar, and put into your projects's reference libraries. - Where is exactly 'projects' reference library'? How to put .jar file in that 'reference library 
2. put backport_android_bluetooth.properties in to your src directory. -Is this file to be put in 'src' folder or '*Project_Name*' folder like project.properties file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u r using eclipse than right click on ur project New/Folder, 

give folder name as libs and copy & paste android-bluetooth2.jar in libs folder.

 than right click on libs folder go to Build Path/ Configure Build Path

 Click on Add Jar, select your project/libs/android-bluetooth2.jar

 press ok

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
Do u have any solution for my 2nd query mentioned in the question, which is about 'putting backport_android_bluetooth.properties in to your src directory'?

Answer (score 1):

Put a new file into your src dir,named `backport_android_bluetooth.properties`
and then put the code below in it:

```
#permission_name = ${your package name).PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH
permission_name = com.example.bluetooth.PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH

#request_enable = ${your package name}.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
request_enable = com.example.bluetooth.action.REQUEST_ENABLE

#request_discoverable = ${your package name}.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE
request_discoverable = com.example.bluetooth.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE
```